# Für „gelb werden“ existiert „vergilben“. Gibt es so was für andere Farben?

Tags: verb, adjective

Für *grün* habe ich *vergrünen* gefunden –allerdings nicht in einem Wörterbuch–, das regelmäßiger als *vergilben* aussieht.

- Gibt es so was für andere Farben? (Ich erwarte keine lange Liste. Denn es würde mich nicht überraschen, dass nur ein paar Verben mehr auftauchen[1]. )
- Was passiert, wenn jemand so ein nicht-existierendes Verb nutzt? Etwa mit diesem Aufbau:

  ```
  werden zu Farbe = Präfix-"ver" + "Farbe" + (e)n
  ```
- Würden die Deutschsprachigen das verstehen?

---

[1] *Offtopic Bemerkung*: Vermutlich überwiegend für zu  alltäglichen Prozessen zugeordnete Farben: Z.B. existiert *vergilben*, weil die Seiten vieler Bücher, die Zähne *vergilben* usw. aber man sieht kaum, dass etwas zu Purpur wird.

Comment: Der einzigen mir geläufigen vergleichbaren Ausdrücke sind *verblassen* und *sich [Farbe] verfärben.*

Comment: Das geht natürlich immer, aber es kann sich etwas durchaus auch *röten*, *bräunen* oder *schwärzen*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wenn du dich nicht auf das Präfix `ver-` festlegst, dann findest du einige weitere:

> erröten
>
> ergrauen
>
> ergrünen
>
> begrünen
>
> einbläuen (nicht die Wortbedeutung, die früher als `einbleuen` geschrieben wurde)
>
> einschwärzen

Die Vorsilbe `ver-` drückt halt u. a. eine negative Entwicklung bzw. eine Auflösung aus. Beim Gelbwerden von Buchseiten nimmt das der Sprachgebrauch so wahr. Bei den anderen Beispielen eben nicht.

Interessant sind dann doch noch die Beispiele mit `ver-`, die sich aber eigentlich nicht auf die Farbe, sondern das Metall beziehen:

> versilbern
>
> vergolden

Und wenn `kupfer` als Farbe akzeptiert:

> verkupfern

Comment: Tschuldigung, dann existiert *vergrünen* nicht?

Comment: vergrünende Streptokokken

Comment: Vorsicht mit einbläuen/einblä(ehemals e)uen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Danke für den Hinweis. Laut http://dwds.de/?qu=einbl%C3%A4uen könnte es die gemeinsame indoeuropäische Wurzel `*bheleu-*` geben (blau → indoeuropäisch: `*bhel-*`), was aber unsicher ist. Selbst wenn, kommt einbläuen nicht von blau (Volksethymologie), sondern die Wörter sind erst in neuerer Zeit wieder ähnlich.

Comment: [Einbläuen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/einbläuen#Verb_2) war schon OK. Es ist abgeleitet von [bläuen](http://dwds.de/?qu=bl%C3%A4uen&submit_button=Suche&view=1), nicht bleuen.

Comment: Vorsicht: neben dem Überziehen mit Metall haben die Begriffe "versilbern" und "vergolden" noch weitere Bedeutungen: versilben = etwas zu Geld machen, verkaufen; vergolden = sich etwas gut bezahlen lassen.

Comment: Vergrauen: z.B. bei Wäsche. Ähnlich wie vergilben meist ein Prozess, der sich über einge Zeit hinzieht.

Answer (score 2):

»**blauen**«

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/blauen):

> **Bedeutungen:**
>   *dichterisch:* blau werden (besonders vom Himmel)
>
> **Beispiele:**
>   Der Himmel blaut über dem Meer.